# BASH : On OSX, how to list a folder randomly?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to generate a list of files located in a certain folder, randomly. I tried to list folder using l -S in order to sort files by size, but it's not totally random. Do you have best idea ?

My script is something like :

```
for FILE in `ls $FOLDER`

do

...

done
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Build a list of the files using `ls`, one entry per line
2. Use `sort` with `--random-sort` to shuffle the results

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is I'm under OSX and it seems I'm not able to use --random-sort...